# Chrome or Chromium Autoplay Muted Loop only loops a few times for larger videos. How do I make large videos loop indefinitely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, nginx, chromium

Example 1:
Video MP4
Size is 118mb
Loops 3 times
[Large Video on Autoplay loop muted](https://pictureinapi.com/users/1/boards/bgg-1)

Example 2:
Video MP4
Size is 6.4mb
Loops indefinitely
[Small Video on Autoplay Loop Muted](https://pictureinapi.com/users/1/boards/girls-dancing)

Changing Video from MP4 to some other more compressed option doesn't seem user friendly, so I'd rather that not be a solution.

I've adjusted `Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public`, but that didn't seem to do anything. I've read about disabling HTTP 200 responses, but haven't found a good way to do that with NGINX or RoR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to employ several different cache based solutions. I recommend reading the following article [A Caching Journey](https://bitcrowd.dev/caching-with-active-storage).

Added to Show action on controller to:

```
    expires_in 24.hours
    fresh_when(:etag => @board, :last_modified => @board.created_at.utc)
```

In Config/environment/production.rb added

```
ActiveStorage::Service.url_expires_in = 3.hours
```

In Config/Storage.yml added

```
 upload:
    cache_control: 'max-age=86400, private'
```